# data from plist is loading detail view in a dark screen

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

So i have set a plist and everytime someone click on the cell in table view i want it to load in the detail view. The only problem is that when it is clicked it loads a dark black screen with nothing on it. Any suggestions?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"Index Selected,%d",indexPath.row);

WebViewController *modalView = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

NSString *urltoPass = [NSString stringWithString:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"cellSubtitle"]];

modalView.urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://%@",urltoPass];
modalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:modalView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Don't edit your questions for different problems, ask new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to actually present the new view controller. You have to add the following line to the bottom of your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
[self presentViewController:modalView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Also, you can remove the line below entirely as it doesn't do anything in its current form.

```
[self.navigationController modalTransitionStyle];
```

Comment: thanks @0x7fffffff ok so i did the following changes, but now it's just taking me to a black screen.